# libphonenumber node.js formats number to intl format even if it is invalid

Tags: node.js, libphonenumber

I am using the libphonenumber library for node.js

In the google [demo for this library](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html), if I enter an invalid phone number, the intl format is not populated. But when I try to parse an invalid number via node.js library, it creates the intl string representation irrespective of whether the number is valid or not.

I need to make sure that only valid numbers are converted and invalids to return null.

As an example, consider this:

```
var phoneProto = phoneUtil.parse("12213", "IN");
phoneProto.intl = phoneUtil.format(phoneProto, 1);
sails.log.debug(phoneProto.intl);
```

Output

```
+91 12213
```

How can I make sure only valid ones are returned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the library's documentation,

**parse(java.lang.String numberToParse,
                         java.lang.String defaultRegion)**

> Parses a string and returns it in proto buffer format. This method will throw a NumberParseException if the number is not considered to be a possible number. **Note that validation of whether the number is actually a valid number for a particular region is not performed. This can be done separately with isValidNumber(PhoneNumber).**